# What is the proper design to deal with this?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, refactoring

I'm working on a legacy Java application, that deals with "fruits" and "vegetables", let's say, for the sake of the question.
They are treated as different things internally, cause they don't have all methods/properties in common, but a lot of things are DONE very similar to both of them.

So, we have a ton of methods *doSomethingWithAFruit(Fruit f)* and *doSomethingWithAVegetable(Veg v)*, that use the proper *doOtherStuffWithAFruit(Fruit f)* / *doOtherStuffWithAVeg(Veg v)*. And those are very similar, except that methods that do things with fruits only call the methods that do things with fruits, and the same thing for vegetables.

I want to refactor this to reduce the duplication, but I'm not sure what is the best way to accomplish that. I've read a bit about some design patterns, but I don't know if it has made any clearer to me. (I can recognize some patterns in the code I use, but I don't really know when I should be applying a pattern to improve things around. Maybe I should be reading more about refactoring itself...)

I was thinking of these two options:

**1.** Creating a class that can have an instance of either a Fruit or a Vegetable and pass it around to the methods, trying to minimize the duplication. It would go like this:

```
public void doSomething(Plant p) {
   // do the stuff that is  common, and then...
   if (p.hasFruit()) {
       doThingWithFruit(p.getFruit());
   } else {
       doThingWithVegetable(p.getVegetable());
   }
}
```

This would get things a bit better, but I don't know... it still feels wrong.

**2.** The other alternative I thought was to put an interface in Fruit and Vegetable with the stuff that is common to them, and use that to pass it around. I feel this is the cleaner approach, although I will have to use `instanceof` and cast to Fruit/Vegetable when it needs stuff that is specific to them.

So, what more can I do here? And what are the shortcomings of these approaches?

**UPDATE:** Note that the question is a bit simplified, I'm looking for way to do things WITH the "plants", that is, code that mostly "uses" them instead of doing things TO them. Having said that, those similar methods I refer to cannot be inside the "Plants" classes, and they usually have another argument, like:

```
public void createSomethingUsingFruit(Something s, Fruit f);
public void createSomethingUsingVegetable(Something s, Vegetable v);
```

Namely, those methods have other concerns besides Fruits/Vegetables, and aren't really appropriated to be in any Fruit/Vegetable class.

**UPDATE 2:** Most code in those methods only reads state from the Fruit/Vegetable objects, and create instances of other classes according to the appropriate type, store in the database and so on -- *from my answer to a question in the comments that I think it's important*.

Comment: What if the plant is not a fruit or a vegetable?

Comment: I think you've got the right idea to head towards a generic interface. Read up on collections also. Perhaps create a class of type <edible> defining any methods, objects, variables you need to be flexible as <edible> then making that concrete in your main/runtime.

Comment: If you can implement common functions for both ( assuming based on the duplicates you mentioned), It is better to use abstract class as you can have implementation on the class it self which will definitley reduce the duplicate code on subclass.

Comment: @PeterLawrey Yeah, my example is lame, I could just use an else/if and throw an IllegalArgumentException if needed. In the real application, though, there will be only these two types.

Comment: Do Fruits and/or Vegetables change state when something is done with them? Like a member integer being increased or anything like that.

Comment: @Fildor Great question! :) No, they are basically read-only. Most code only reads state from them and create instances of other classes according to the appropriate type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option you can use, or perhaps include it as part of your solution, is to ask the consumer if it can manage the object that you are passing it.  At this point, it becomes the consumer's responsibility to ensure it knows how to handle the object you are sending it.

For instance, if your consumer is called Eat, you would do something like:

```
Consumer e = new Eat();
Consumer w = new Water();
if( e.canProcess( myFruit ) )
   e.doSomethingWith( myFruit );
else if ( w.canProcess( myFruit ) )
   w.doSomethingWith( myFruit );

.... etc
```

But then you end up with a lot of it/else classes, so you create yourself a Factory which determines which consumer you want.  Your Factory basically does the if/else branching to determine which consumer can handle the object you pass, and returns the consumer to you.

So it looks something like

```
public class Factory {
   public static Consumer getConsumer( Object o ){
    Consumer e = new Eat();
    Consumer w = new Water();
    if( e.canProcess( o ) )
       return e;
    else if ( w.canProcess( o ) )
       return w;
   }
}
```

Then your code becomes:

```
Consumer c = Factory.getConsumer( myFruit );
c.doSomethingWith( myFruit );
```

Of course in the `canProcess` method of the consumer, it would be basically an instanceof or some other function your derive to determine if it can handle your class.

```
public class Eat implements Consumer{
   public boolean canProcess(Object o ){
     return o instanceof Fruit;
   }
}
```

So you end up shifting the responsibility from your class to a Factory class to determine which objects can be handled.  The trick, of course, is that all Consumers must implement a common interface.

I realize that my pseudo-code is very basic, but it is just to point out the general idea.  This may or may not work in your case and/or become overkill depending on how your classes are structured, but if well designed, can significantly improve readability of your code, and truely keep all logic for each type self-contained in their own class without instanceof and if/then scattered everywhere.

Comment: Hi! It would be a bit of an overkill to do this for the kind of methods I am dealing with right now, but I'm probably going to find a place where I'm gonna need something like it to get a good separation. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

I think the 2nd approach would be better.. Designing to an interface is always a better way to design.. That way you can switch between your implementation easily..

And if you use interfaces, you won't need to do typecast as you can easily exploit the concept of `polymorphism`.. That is, you will have `Base class reference pointing to a subclass object..

But if you want to keep only methods common to `fruits` and `vegetables` in your interface, and specific implementation in your implementation class.. Then in that case `typecasting` would be required..

So, you can have a generic method at interface level.. And more specific method at implementation level..

```
public interface Food {
    public void eat(Food food);
}

public class Fruit implements Food {

    // Can have interface reference as parameter.. But will take Fruit object    
    public void eat(Food food) {
        / ** Fruit specific task **/
    }
}

public class Vegetable implements Food {

    // Can have interface reference as parameter.. But will take Vegetable object
    public void eat(Food food) {
        /** Vegetable specific task **/
    }
}

public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
         Food fruit = new Fruit();
         fruit.eat(new Fruit());    // Invoke Fruit Version

         Food vegetable = new Vegetable();
         vegetable.eat(new Vegetable());   // Invoke vegetable version

    }
}
```

OK, I have modified a code to make `eat()` method to take parameters of type `Food`.. That will not make much of a difference.. You can pass `Vegetable` object to `Food` reference..

Comment: +1 I would try to make `Food` and `doSomething` have related names like interface `Iterable` and method `iterator()` do

Comment: Hi! The thing is, the code in the methods are not really concerns of Fruit or Vegetable. I've updated my question trying to be more clear. Thanks for your attention anyway! :)

Comment: @eljunior. I have modified my code a little bit.. Take a look at it whether it solves your problem.. Is is what you were asking??

Comment: @eljunior.. Your `UPDATE 2` in your post concerns me.. What other objects you want to make from your derived class object??

Comment: @RohitJain Sorry for the delay... So, these Fruit/Vegetable objects are read from an external database, and then the app have some code to store a sort of history of them. Those are the instances I was referring to in `UPDATE 2`. Thanks for your attention, by the way!

Comment: @eljunior.. How are you fetching object from database?? Are you creating object from the data fetched??

Comment: I'm using JPA but I don't think it really matters to this issue. These objects are read elsewhere, those methods just receive arguments that eventually were read from a database. I just mentioned it so you know there are other stuff involved. So, I am creating other objects (not Fruit/Vegetable) using the data got from the Fruit/Vegetable objects.

Answer (score 1):

If you have functionality that is specific to fruits and vegetables respectively and a client using both types has to distinguish (using `instanceof`) - that is a coherence vs. coupling problem.

Maybe consider if said functionality is not better placed near fruit and vegetable themselves instead of with the client. The client may then somehow be refered to the functionality (through a generic interface) not caring what instance he is dealing with. Polymorphism would be preserved at least from the client's perspective.

But that is theoretical and may not be practical or be over-engineered for your use case. Or you could end up actually just hiding `instanceof` somewhere else in your design. `instanceof` is going to be a bad thing when you start having more inheritance siblings next to fruits and vegetables. Then you would start violating the [Open Closed Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Closed_Principle).

Comment: Hmm... Thanks, very reasonable answer. In my case, it's pretty certain there won't be any other sibling. I'm just trying to reorganize stuff. I think I still am going with my first option.

Answer (score 0):

I would create and abstract base class (let's say - Food, but I don't know your domain, something else might fit better) and start to migrate methods to it one after another.

In case you see that 'doSomethingWithVeg' and 'doSomthingWithFruit' are slightly different - create the 'doSomething' method at the base class and use abstract methods to do only the parts that are different (I guess the main business logic can be united, and only minor issues like write to DB/file are different).

When you have one method ready - test it. After you're sure it's ok - go to the other one. When you are done, the Fruit and Veg classes shouldn't have any methods but the implementations of the abstract ones (the tiny differences between them).

Hope it helps..

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic OOD question. since fruits and vegetables are of type Plant.
I would suggest:

```
interface Plant {
    doSomething();
}

class Vegetable {
    doSomething(){
    ....
    }
}
```

and the same with the fruit.

it seems to me that doOtherStuff methods should be private for the relevant class.

Answer (score 0):

You can also consider having them both implement multiple interfaces instead of just one. That way you code against the most meaningful interface according the circumstances which will help avoid casting. Kind of what `Comparable<T>` does. It helps the methods (like the ones that sort objects), where they don't care what the objects are, the only requirement is that they have to be comparable. e.g. in your case both can implement some interfaces called `Edible`, then take both of them as `Edible` where an `Edible` is expected.